Airflow not running locally
I am trying to run airflow locally using make airflow-up
I have a config file with the passwords in .aws
I'm getting this error
    WARN[0000] The "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
    WARN[0000] The "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
    WARN[0000] The "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
    WARN[0000] The "AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?


looks like your docker compose file depends on AWS creds, set values of the respective variables in .env file in the project root directory like:
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
...

